# Do digital signal isolators shift the level of the signal

Tags: digital-isolator

I am using 2 digital signal isolators, the [ISOW7841](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/isow7841.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-digikeymode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1590098995360) and the [ISO7730](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso7730-q1.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-digikeymode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1589745035890).

[image]

The datasheet does not seem to explicitly say that if a signal coming from the 5V side comes out 3.3V on the other side or vice versa. I just want to make sure.

Do digital signal isolators inherently shift the voltage level of the signal?

Comment: To me, shift = offset. But I assume you actually mean translate, as in logic level translation. Yes they do, and yes it does say. Look at the input and output logic thresholds in the datasheet.

Comment: @DKNguyen ohhh, i did not notice it because as i was skimming it its unit was mA and the symbol was Ioh and Iol. Please make you comment as answer sir, ill accept it

Comment: You're still looking at the wrong section I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, shift = offset. But I assume you actually mean translate, as in logic level translation. Yes they do, and yes it does say. Look at the input and output logic thresholds in the datasheet.

**ISO773x**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**ISO784x**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simpler answer is on page 1 of the data sheet for the ISOW7841: -

[image]

And for the ISO7730 there is this on page 1 of the data sheet: -

[image]